# How many rackets did he throw away?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Siva bought $\$945$ worth of rackets at $\$7$ each. He had to throw some away as they were damaged. He sold the rest at $\$9$ each and collected $\$1116$.

How many rackets did he throw away?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Siva bought $\dfrac{\$945}{\$7} = 135$ rackets.

**He threw away $x$ of them.** Hence $135 - x$ good rackets remain.

He sold the remaining $135 - x$ rackets at $\$9$ each and collected $\$1116$. Solve for $x$, given $$\begin{align} 9(135 - x) &= 1116 \\ \\\iff 135 - x & = \dfrac {1116}{9} = 124 \\\\  \iff x & = 135 - 124 = 11\end{align}$$

Comment: What an expensive hobby! :-) +1

Comment: Does this help any, @Nitinivi? If so, feel free to *accept* the answer (just click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer, but you can accept only one answer per question. You get two extra reputation points when you accept an answer to one of your questions.)

Answer (score 1):

945/7=135, and 1116/9=124. He bought 135, and sold 124. How many did he throw away?